# How to run sbt Revolver in test scope?

Tags: sbt, sbt-revolver

In a Akka project we're using the SBT Revolver plugin to run the application.
During development it would be useful if it would be possible to run the application in test scope so log- and application configuration get loaded which helps during development.

However, running 'sbt test:re-start' does not seems to use the test classpath and therefore does not run the correct application and does not use the correct configuration files.

Looking at the [Revolver page](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) it looks like the plugin creates it's own scope.
Does anyone know how to be able to use the test scope for running the Revolver plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the fullClasspath setting of revolver and add the Test classpath to it:

```
fullClasspath in Test in reStart <<= Classpaths.concatDistinct(fullClasspath in Test, fullClasspath in Runtime)
```